# Spring 3 and NTLM authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ntlm

I am using a spring 3 web application, as Spring 3 doesn't support NTLM authentication, what are the other alternatives that can be used along with Spring security? So that users are authenticated to application when they log into Active Directory?

Kerberos solution is not an option at the moment, NTLM is the only option.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: NTLM is proprietary, don't expect to find a working solution in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it one time. Grab it [here](https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/springsecurity3-activedirectory-ntlm-test). It will required to do some small setup at AD level. Feel free to ask questions here or on github.

Comment: What is the setup require at AD level? And I am using Weblogic 10.3.6, so any compatability issues?

Comment: Just to create account with type "computer" and execute SetComputerAccountPasswordWindows7.vbs on AD server.
Should work with Weblogic 10.3.6 without any problem.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to solve your problem is the following:

1)  Install Apache Web Server and configure to use NTLM authentication using modntlm

http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/
(Similar you can use Kerberos authentication using mod_auth_kerb using http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/)

2)  Configure mod_jk to your Selvlet container (JBoss or Tomcat)
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html
After the successful authentication Apache sends the REMOTE_USER header to the servlet container.
The header (according the name) contains a user name of the authenticated user
Ensure you configure tomcatAuthentication="false" to allow Apache to allow apache to send the REMOTE_USER header

3) Implement and configure in Spring Security your own PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6167
It should be very similar to the Request-Header Authentication filter:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6295
In addition, you should omit a domain name from the user name.
The user name is sent in the REMOTE_USER header after NTLM or Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Waffle is drop in solution that can be used with springsecurity to achieve this:
https://github.com/dblock/waffle

I've used it myself with for example hybris. They have some examples. Beware of version 1.5 that uses jna3.5 which can cause problems at high load
Also beware that you may need to extend negotiatesecurityfilter if our application needs to do authorization(I had to do that, may be fixed in 1.6.