# How to use database authentication with the logged in user from windows OS on Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, ntlm

I am working on a Spring batch project which will be running on a Windows machine where I have to use NTLM authentication instead of taking the credentials from property file.

It would be great help If I could get some guidance on how to implement it using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

As you were just looking for guidance on how to implement this in Spring, a contributor on github has a page about this:

[Spring Security 3 + Active Directory + NTLMv2](https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/springsecurity3-activedirectory-ntlm-test)

More information concerning the above link, helpful hints from the contributor, and alternative suggestions to this strategy, can be found in this SO thread:  [Spring 3 and NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533226/spring-3-and-ntlm-authentication)