# mod_ntlm with Camel http4 component

Tags: authentication, apache-camel, ntlm, http4s

Hi all,

Is there known limitations with using the Camel http4 component to authenticate to a mod_ntlm protected endpoint?

In our Camel service, I am able to successfully authentication to NTLM protected endpoints which is protected using jcifs setup, but get the following error hitting the mod_ntlm protected service:

```
ntlm_decode_msg failed: type: 1, host: "", user: "", domain: "", error: 3
missing/corrupt NTLM header
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get the mod_ntlm module?  I've been looking for that and unable to find it.  *yum install mod_ntlm* on CentOS 7 returns 'No package mod_ntlm available'.

Comment: This is an internal service so I'm not sure of the setup, but I came across this if its any use to you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533226/spring-3-and-ntlm-authentication
The answer from Michael has a description of how to setup mod_ntlm

Comment: Thank you sir!!  If I get any time I will replicate this and respond back to the question.